# socket.io and android secure connection (handshake) - Logic question

Tags: java, android, socket.io, handshake

**Hi :)** and greetings from Berlin

I have a question about handshake and a secure connection. I am developing my first Android APP with Socket.IO Server.

My question is, how do I make sure that only "my" client can connect to the server and no other clients that simply connect to my IP address + PORT.
I have read something about tokens but I lack experience here.

Does anyone have a good example with code or an existing tutorial ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can  use an Authorization header with Socket IO . Read the documentation.

Comment: See https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#nodejs-with-extraheaders.

Comment: Hi @ADM , thanks for your fast answer.
So I have to add with socketIO (Extra Header) the authorization token in the client and check for match on service side ?
I haven't understood the logic behind it with the authorization and tokens

Comment: The logic behind it is Once the Session initiated you should assign a Unique Token to each user . And each time user tried to connect Socket it has to have the Auth header. I can not make any assumption since i do not know your app's server structure .